# android EditText UI freezing after firebase call

Tags: android, firebase, android-edittext

I am currently developing a chat application and I have encountered a problem with the EditText from which I get the user input and send it to the database. The following is a test which is similar to the actual code but still causes the EditText UI to lag:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = chat.getText().toString();

            Message message = new Message(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000)),user,text,new Date());
            sendMessage(message);

            chat.getText().clear();



        }
    });

}


private void sendMessage(Message message){
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mDatabaseRef.child("messagesTest").child("chat")
            .push()
            .setValue(message);





}
```

When i remove the `sendMessage(message)` method the edittext doesnt lag ie I can input texts multiple times but when I try to send to it to the database, it works fine the first time and on trying the second time the EditText UI lags.

Below are my logs (which has no error as far as I can see)

```
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 281924(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 35% free, 10MB/16MB, paused 1.806ms total 157.154ms
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for saved_photos found on class com.project.beautyapp.models.UserAccountSettings
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for saved_photos found on class com.project.beautyapp.models.UserAccountSettings
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 144593(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 21MB/27MB, paused 2.984ms total 380.004ms
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 541417(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 20MB/26MB, paused 825us total 340.997ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 547964(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 25MB/31MB, paused 692us total 484.181ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 695852(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 32MB/38MB, paused 1.443ms total 1.252s
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 685921(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 40MB/46MB, paused 720us total 1.206s
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1128588(24MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 41MB/47MB, paused 799us total 1.067s
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 878928(19MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 57MB/63MB, paused 1.591ms total 1.313s
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 1436453(31MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 61MB/67MB, paused 695us total 1.480s
I/Choreographer: Skipped 516 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=8648ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=12489910358633, Vsync=12498510358289, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=12498512645661, AnimationStart=12498512736661, PerformTraversalsStart=12498513538661, DrawStart=12498514299661, SyncQueued=12498514614661, SyncStart=12498514757661, IssueDrawCommandsStart=12498514832661, SwapBuffers=12498515692661, FrameCompleted=12498559353661, DequeueBufferDuration=165000, QueueBufferDuration=17743000, 
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 1507175(32MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 40MB/46MB, paused 870us total 651.806ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 888402(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 32MB/38MB, paused 1.804ms total 429.933ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 651130(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 28MB/34MB, paused 770us total 243.461ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 497664(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 29MB/35MB, paused 717us total 446.037ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 542572(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 28MB/34MB, paused 792us total 259.961ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 469682(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 31MB/37MB, paused 818us total 464.431ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 596357(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 28MB/34MB, paused 739us total 266.602ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 464576(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 31MB/37MB, paused 801us total 414.198ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 527117(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 33MB/39MB, paused 816us total 416.902ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 602423(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 34MB/40MB, paused 831us total 531.183ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 530 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=8864ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=12498557124661, Vsync=12507390457641, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=12507402630661, AnimationStart=12507402682661, PerformTraversalsStart=12507402713661, DrawStart=12507403451661, SyncQueued=12507403837661, SyncStart=12507404306661, IssueDrawCommandsStart=12507404467661, SwapBuffers=12507405464661, FrameCompleted=12507422298661, DequeueBufferDuration=579000, QueueBufferDuration=1973000, 
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 624872(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 34MB/40MB, paused 1.257ms total 850.488ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 642067(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 32MB/38MB, paused 850us total 458.440ms
I/oject.beautyap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 533375(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 33MB/39MB, paused 760us total 454.370ms
I/oject.beautyap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked NativeAlloc on HeapTrim for 31.920s
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/oject.beautyap: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/Choreographer: Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1272ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=12974332351673, Vsync=12975582351623, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=12975590072661, AnimationStart=12975590142661, PerformTraversalsStart=12975591699661, DrawStart=12975598714661, SyncQueued=12975599468661, SyncStart=12975599538661, IssueDrawCommandsStart=12975599641661, SwapBuffers=12975603389661, FrameCompleted=12975605028661, DequeueBufferDuration=91000, QueueBufferDuration=772000, 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/oject.beautyap: Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 3692263(79MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 256MB/262MB, paused 1.233ms total 3.988s
I/oject.beautyap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 2.935s
I/oject.beautyap: Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
I/oject.beautyap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Explicit on ProfileSaver for 992.402ms
I/oject.beautyap: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 2504022(55MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 258MB/264MB, paused 1.273ms total 4.006s
I/oject.beautyap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked NativeAlloc on ProfileSaver for 21.232s
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 2387985(51MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 260MB/266MB, paused 3.574ms total 2.692s
I/oject.beautyap: Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
I/oject.beautyap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/oject.beautyap: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 2498214(56MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 322MB/328MB, paused 796us total 2.794s
I/oject.beautyap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Explicit on HeapTrim for 2.226s
I/oject.beautyap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems sendMessage() is Synchronous.

You can to:

```
final Message message = new Message(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000)), user, text, new Date());
//v.setEnabled(false);
v.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendMessage(message);
        //v.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

but in this way the user could press the button very quickly and queue many "sendMessage(...)" request. To avoid it you could use "v.setEnabled(false);" before the "v.post()" and set again to TRUE after "sendMessage()".

Move to different Thread:

```
final Message message = new Message(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000)), user, text, new Date());
//v.setEnabled(false);
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendMessage(message);
        /*
        if (v.isAttachedToWindow()) v.post(new Runnable() {
            if (v.isAttachedToWindow()) v.setEnabled(false);
        });
        */
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I don't think sendMessage() is synchronous cause Firebase handles all its requests asynchronously. I've also tried what you suggest but the problem is still there

Comment: If removing "sendMessage()" solves the problem, then thare is an high probability that it's Synchronous. I think you have to move "sendMessage()" in another Thread. I've edited my anwser (i'ts just a test because the right way to do this is different)

Comment: even after putting it in a  background thread, the main UI thread still freezes

Comment: Then Firebase Instance run itself/internally in the Main/UiThread. Without knowing what all Firebase methods do UNDER THE HOOD it's impossible to help you more.... Sorry.

Comment: Actually i was able to isolate the problem, i ignore all other activities and made the activity in question as the mainActivity and the problem isn't there, so i assume that maybe there are some long running tasks that are running on the UI thread which are slowing down the application. So i'll try move those tasks to a background thread

Comment: You can profile CPU usage using Android Studio Profiler panel to check who cause the CPU issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_layout);
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = chat.getText().toString();
        Message message = new Message(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000)),new User(),"it will work",new Date());
        sendMessage(message);
        chat.setText("");
    }
});


private void sendMessage(Message message){
    mDatabaseRef.child("messagesTest").child("chat")
        .push()
        .setValue(message);
```

}